# What is the window left bottom message?

Tags: javascript, browser

When we are loading particular website, we used to get notifications / messages at left bottom corner like:

- waiting for www.stackoverflow.com
- waiting for cache & etc.

I am just wondering:

- what we call that message / notification?
- Can we add our custom messages over there?

Please refer below image.
[image: Web left bottom notification / message]

Comment: its the status bar notifications (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-happened-status-bar)

Comment: It seems related to chrome only which we can't change and it can't be [turned off](http://superuser.com/a/239368/165731). There is a weird trick to add custom message though (_or hide_). Here is the [fiddle](http://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/qZZGjw?editors=1010) taken from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28206011/1577396).