# How to hide browser status popup for full screen mode?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I have a PHP website that is used to manually control a dynamic presentation on a separate monitor in full screen (F11) mode.

The problem is that every time the browser navigates between "slides", the status bar appears in the left bottom corner saying Connecting, Waiting etc.

Is there any way to disable the status bar from my application or from browser settings or some other hacky options to get rid of it?

We are using Firefox or Chrome because they seem to have the best support for our implemented CSS3 animations with advanced features, such as mask-image etc. But I'm open to other browser suggestions if it doesn't display that status popup in full screen mode while navigating.

To be sure which thing I'm talking about, here's a video from another user complaining about that status popup:

https://youtu.be/PWbV_RhzJ_s

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28206011/4904726). Here is the solution that helped me. Maybe you will need to handle not only 'a' elements.

```
$("body").on('mouseover', 'a', function (e) {
    var $link = $(this),
        href = $link.attr('href') || $link.data("href");

    $link.off('click.chrome');
    $link.on('click.chrome', function () {
        window.location.href = href;
    })
    .attr('data-href', href) //keeps track of the href value
    .css({ cursor: 'pointer' })
    .removeAttr('href'); // <- this is what stops Chrome to display status bar
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this would help to hide status bar on the primary screen where links and buttons are, but unfortunately it doesn't prevent that "Loading..." popup in the second full screen browser window.